# Datetime string to number of milliseconds

Tags: datetime, sqlite

I pull data from a websource and it returns time in the format 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSZ'. Since I would be doing a lot of comparisons on this column, I thought it would be best to store them as the number of millliseconds since epoch (I need millisecond precision!!). What would be the best way to convert the incoming datetime string to number of milliseconds?

I tried to use

`strftime('%s', datetimeString)` - gives back the number of seconds since epoch till datetimeString

`strftime('%f', datetimeString)` - gives back only the SS.SSS part!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing it has something to do with SQLite [**not** having actual Date or Datetime types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) (section 1.2). Instead it formats them as one of:

- an ISO8601 string (`TEXT` type)
- a floating point number of days (`REAL` type)
- an integer number of seconds since the epoch time (`INTEGER` type)

The `REAL` data type may not have enough precision to store a date, time, and fractional seconds in a single field.

It seems the answer is one of:

- store them as two separate fields, the datetime in one, and the fractional seconds in another
- do the integer number of milliseconds calculation yourself and store the integer result in a single column, so long as the maximum level of fractional second precision you need will fit in a signed integer of 8-bytes or fewer (the maximum size for the `INTEGER` type in SQLite3)
- [switch databases to a DBMS that supports real date/datetime types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-datetime.html)

Without switching your DB, and if you never need sub-millisecond precision, then I'd at least try the "manual calculation + single integer column" solution and see if it works.

Comment: Since I am working on android, I believe I have no choice but to use sqlite3. As to the other 2 suggestions, I believe that the second option would suit me best as the datetime object won't be split across columns

Comment: Something told me you might be on mobile, which would, of course, point you toward SQLite if this is an in-app DB. Good luck!